# specify PREFIX location when running make

Tags: software-installation, compiling, rpm

I need to install redis 2.8.x into a specific directory so I can later use [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) to create an rpm.

From my research, it seems that this should be possible by using `make PREFIX=`

```
mkdir /tmp/installdir
cd /tmp
wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-2.8.6.tar.gz
tar -xvf redis-*.tar.gz
cd redis-2.8.6
make PREFIX=/tmp/installdir
make install
```

I expect the binaries to be placed in /tmp/installdir, unfortunately that directory remains empty. It seems `PREFIX=/tmp/installdir` is being ignored.

Normally I would run `./configure --prefix=/tmp/installdir` however because the download does not contain source code, there is no `configure` file.

How can I install software to a non standard directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was successful by prefixing

```
PREFIX=/tmp/installdir make
```

and

```
PREFIX=/tmp/installdir make install
```

to check what happens, use `-n`

```
root@wizzard:/tmp/redis-2.8.6# PREFIX=/tmp/installdir make install -n
cd src && make install
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/redis-2.8.6/src'
echo ""
echo "Hint: To run 'make test' is a good idea ;)"
echo ""
mkdir -p /tmp/installdir/bin
printf '    %b %b\n' "\033[34;1m"INSTALL"\033[0m" "\033[37;1m"install"\033[0m" 1>&2;install redis-server /tmp/installdir/bin
printf '    %b %b\n' "\033[34;1m"INSTALL"\033[0m" "\033[37;1m"install"\033[0m" 1>&2;install redis-benchmark /tmp/installdir/bin
printf '    %b %b\n' "\033[34;1m"INSTALL"\033[0m" "\033[37;1m"install"\033[0m" 1>&2;install redis-cli /tmp/installdir/bin
printf '    %b %b\n' "\033[34;1m"INSTALL"\033[0m" "\033[37;1m"install"\033[0m" 1>&2;install redis-check-dump /tmp/installdir/bin
printf '    %b %b\n' "\033[34;1m"INSTALL"\033[0m" "\033[37;1m"install"\033[0m" 1>&2;install redis-check-aof /tmp/installdir/bin
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/redis-2.8.6/src'
```

Answer (score 1):

The redis's `Makefile` doesn't use a variable PREFIX at all. If you want PREFIX to be specified for the commands run from the Makefile you should use:

```
PREFIX=/tmp/installdir make
```